# Are "Multimodal" and "Non-Convex" Synonyms?

Tags: probability, optimization, machine-learning

**Part 1:** In the context of probability, the following optimization problem is often called "**Multi-Modal**" as it is a sum of different Normal Distributions, and each distribution has its own "mode" - therefore it is "multi modal". Furthermore, this is said to be a difficult optimization problem due to its multi-modality (presumably because of multiple local minima/maxima):

\begin{align*}
p(x|\theta) &= \sum_{i=1}^{k} \pi_i \mathcal{N}(x|\mu_i, \sigma_i^2) 
\end{align*}

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \pi_i = 1$$

Optimization Problem:
\begin{align*} 
L(\theta|X) &= \prod_{j=1}^{n} p(x_j|\theta) = \prod_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{k} \pi_i \mathcal{N}(x_j|\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)
\end{align*}

**Part 2:** In Machine Learning, the loss function of a neural network is usually "**Non-Convex**" as there are multiple local minima and local maxima (and saddle points). This too is a difficult optimization problem:

\begin{equation}
L(w_1, w_2, ..., w_n) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} L_i(y_i, f(x_i; w_1, w_2, ..., w_n))
\end{equation}

**My Question:** Given these examples, is it correct to say that "Multi-Modal" and "Non-Convex" are basically synonyms? They both refer to complex and irregular surfaces : a Multi-Modal function is likely Non-Convex and a Non-Convex function is Multi-Modal.

Is my understanding correct? Multi-Modal and Non-Convex are the same thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Non-convex function need not be multmodal.

Comment: @ Mark : thank you for your reply! Can you please explain this? Isnt each global minima effectively a mode?

Comment: Some non-convex functions have only one local optimum, and which is also a and the only global optimum.